# What is the best way to retain Java WebSocket sessions for later retrieval by other Servlets?

Tags: java, session, servlets, websocket, java-websocket

I have a Java WebSocket that currently caches sessions in a static field so other servlets can call a static method to send messages to any listeners (as push to notify of events). It's like:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/events")
public class Events {

  // collection containing all the sessions
  private static final Set<Session> sessions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

  @OnOpen
  public void onOpen(final Session session) {
        // cache the new session
        sessions.add(session);
        ...
  }

  @OnClose
  public void onClose(final Session session) {
        // remove the session
        sessions.remove(session);
  }

  public static void notify(String message) {
        synchronized(sessions) {
          for (Session s : sessions) {
            if (s.isOpen()) {
              try {
                    // send the message
                    s.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
              } catch (IOException ex) { ... }
            }
          }
        }
  }
}
```

Then the servlet can do:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    Events.notify( "some message" );
}
```

But is a static variable the best way? Is there no built-in annotation for caching either a session or a server endpoint for retrieval by other servlets (maybe via `@Context` variables or something else)?

A static variable just doesn't seem like the best way to handle this.

Comment: If the question is still on your agenda, I'm interested as well. In our solution, we use an `@ApplicationScope` which works as a "session handler". The @ApplicationScope is injected in the @ServerEndpoint. Then it's like what you wrote. We avoided having static field in @ServerEndpoint because Websocket handles thread in a rather strange and sometimes unpredictable way